# E-mail address of the conference organizer is not valid?

Tags: conference, email

Currently, I am trying to find a suitable conference to submit my research work for them. I am trying to get in contact with the organizer of this event to answer some related question regarding appendixes and extra attachment in submission.

So, I just searched for the contact person email and sent him my inquiry. In fact, I got a feedback email from the mail system indicating that no user associated with this email address!

I even tried to get in contact with a professor who is involved in this event. Unfortunately, no reply since the last week. I've even mentioned why I am contacting him not the main organizer since the announced email is not working.

[image]

In fact, I have submitted my research paper to their platform and I managed to answer my questions by myself. But I wonder how such a thing is possible.
Normally, what is the proper way to contact them? I tried by email as I said before but no one answers. I tried to call them but they don't have an English speaking person.

Comment: The mail is not valid and they do not have any english speaking person but accept english work to be submitted? That does not sound good to me.

Comment: @skymningen yes. In Germany it's work like this. Becuase the organizers are some people from management while the professors the only who can speak English.

Comment: No, honestly. I am from Germany. It does not work like this, if it does it is highly unprofessional. "No such user" looks quite like a scam where someone made up a university mail address (because they are usually standardised) that does not actually exist.

Comment: @skymningen Actually as we are international students, NO-ONE can deny that Germans don't use English as other countries do and even if they know, they will express it differently. In fact, this question is not about Germany nor any land, it's all about how can an organization put an email to an international event with non-valid email! you can try by your self. http://webintelligence2017.com/

Comment: I am not going to discuss with you the opposite problem I have had of international students not being fluent enough in english. I still think this has large warning signs all over it about being a scam. Where I work, even the secretaries are nearly all multilingual (at least one other language spoken besides German and English). Who is organising an international conference has to speak English, in any other case I tend to disregard the conference as scam.

Comment: @skymningen the only reason I am writing for them because of my German supervisor desire, he wants me to publish with them since he is doing the same over many years. So, it is not scam!

Comment: Let your supervisor contact them if he knows them well.

Comment: @skymningen will be considered as a waste of time...

Comment: I guess it depends on how badly you want to get in touch with these people.  If it's very important, you could spend a few days learning the basic phrases you would need in the target language.  Also, explore the People section of the appropriate department(s).